# Aggregation relationship via JPA annotations

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, model-associations

I am trying to establish the aggregation relationship between two Java classes through JPA annotations in order to persist them into a database.

[image]

```
public class Ticket 
{
    private String ticketNo;
    private Date releasedDate;
    private boolean printed;
}

public class Discount 
{
    private String percentage;
    private Date releasedDate;
    private boolean printed;
}
```

Such as mentioned [here](http://www.classdraw.com/help.htm), the aggregation relationship is unidirectional and thus, only it is necessary to map one side. From the solution given by this [page](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=aggregate.php), I think the solution will be:

```
 public class Discount 
    {
        private String percentage;
        private Date releasedDate;
        private boolean printed;
        @ManyToOne(name="TICKET_ID")
        private Ticket ticket;
    }
```

However, in some [examples of aggregation](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/aggregation/), the many side class appears inside the one side class. Thus, I am considering this too:

```
 public class Ticket 
        {
            private String ticketNo;
            private Date releasedDate;
            private boolean printed;
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="ticket")
            private List<Discount> discounts = new ArrayList<Discount>();
        }
```

Which option is the proper one?

Comment: `So I am not sure if it is right.` why do you think it is not right. Both unidirectional and bidirectional relations are legal and valid.

Comment: Aggregation is unidirectional. My doubt is knowing which side (class) should have the corresponding annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how you map a unidirectional many-to-one relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String ticketNo;
    private Date releasedDate;
    private boolean printed;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Discount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String percentage;
    private Date releasedDate;
    private boolean printed;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_ID")  // you can rename the join column 
    private Ticket ticket;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Note:

- JoinColumn (foreign key in the database terminology) must be on the many side of the relationship (this is the Discount in your case).
- The `@Id` annotations are also mandatory. In this case, the ID will be generated by the persistence provider automatically. If you are using database sequence or table or some other strategy you can redefine it.

Answer (score 2):

That looks right to me. A discount has a ticket. You could also include the discounts accessible from the tickets like `ticket.getDiscounts()` if you need to access them in a query such as `SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.discounts.percentage >= :discountPercentage`.

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    private String ticketNo;
    private Date releasedDate;
    private boolean printed;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Discounts> discounts;
}

@Entity
public class Discount {
       private String percentage;
       private Date releasedDate;
       private boolean printed;

       @ManytoOne(name="TICKET_ID")
       private Ticket ticket;
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using `@OneToMany` as this can create problems serializing too much data to JSON if you are returning this as JSON results or just lazily loading too much data by accident. You should always be able to work with just `@ManyToOne` as an example if you did not put the `@OneToMany` association query can be `SELECT t FROM Discount d INNER JOIN d.ticket t WHERE d.percentage >= :discountPercentage`

Comment: I am newbie with JPA but if I think that, if the relationship is unidirectional, only one annotation should exist in one of the classes. And I am not sure in which side it should be.