# how can i do the mapping of Aggregation and Composotion with JPA and mysql data base?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mapping

[image: Screen shot of the relationship table I want to create]

Are there some annotations in springboot can help me to do this work?

Comment: There is no explicit annotation for Aggregation and Composition. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311717/aggregation-relationship-via-jpa-annotations